# Error 1603 while installing Visual Studios for Hololens Development

Tags: windows, sdk, universal, hololens

I am trying to develop apps for Hololens

After setup of Visual studios 2015 runs and gets completed, With a yellow triangle representing error it states, setup complete. However, not all features installed correctly.

Tools for Universal Windows App(1.4.1) and Windows SDK(10.0.14393)

> The installer Failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code:1603

I have tried to reinstall visual studios community 2015, same error comes. I also tried to uninstall separately Windows SDK 10.0.014393.33 and run the VS setup again, it doesn't help as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend uninstalling visual studio, update Windows to the latest version, redownload the visual studio installer, disable antivirus and try again.  If that doesn't work, Microsoft has a whole forum dedicated to troubleshooting VS install issues at:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vssetup

You are almost certain to get a better response there.

Comment: Also make sure that you run update 3 before you install the sdk